# How to sort varchar values in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to know how to sort ascending or descending varchar values.

This is my field and values
Filling_s_no            varchar2;

Table:

```
Id  Filling_s_no    name
1   1.1.1            X
1   1.1.10           X
1   1.1.5            X
1   1.1.2            X
1   1.2.1            X
1   1.2.0            X
```

Now I want to sort my table like this format

```
Id  Filling_s_no    name
1   1.1.1            X
1   1.1.2            X
1   1.1.5            X
1   1.1.10           X
1   1.2.0            X
1   1.2.1            X
```

I tried with this query but am unable get the solution.

```
select * 
  from TCD_EX_Tab 
 where id=1 
 order by Filling_s_no ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I was trying align this format only.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `filling_s_no` will always have three numeric components separated by periods?  Or might it have two or four or sixty numeric components?  How should elements with more or less than three elements be sorted?  Is there a reason that you're not storing the components separately?  Composite attributes violate all normalization rules and mean that you end up writing a ton of parsing logic to extract the individual components.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will do what you need:

```
SELECT ID, FILLING_S_NO, NAME
  FROM TCD_EX_TAB
  where id=1 
  order BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(filling_s_no, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)),
           TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(filling_s_no, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)),
           TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(filling_s_no, '[0-9]+', 1, 3));
```

The problem to be solved is that the components of the text string need to be converted to numbers in order to sort as you want them to. We use a regular expression to pick out each of the sub-elements of the string, then convert those sub-elements to type NUMBER for sorting purposes.

Best of luck.